# Change format date jj-mm-aaaa to jj/mm/aaaa in JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry, I am beginner in Js. In my input, the format date is as this below

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycl4E.png)

I would like to change the format `jj-mm-aaaa` to `jj/mm/aaaa`. (I just want to change the dash to a slash).

Do you think it's possible?

Comment: Unfortunately not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format

Answer (score -1):

You could use a regular expression:

```
sDate = sDate.replace(/\-/g, '/');
```

or you might like to use a string to array conversion joined again to a string:

```
sDate = sDate.split('-').join('/');
```